# Select from two tables and showing results even if conditions are not met

Tags: mysql

I'm making simple ticket system for internal use, not for public. I have two tables - `tickets` and `ticket_answers`. In `tickets` I store the who started the ticket and when along with body, title .. etc.

In `ticket_answers` I store who is replayed and when on particular ticket. So now on home page I want to show ticket info like: Author of ticket, body, title, date of ticket + last replay author, last replay date...

This is the query so far which is working BUT the ticket is shown on the page only if there is replay. If I create ticket will not be visible because doesn't have answers. So how to modify the query to show tickets with no replays?

```
SELECT tickets.*, ticket_answers.*
    FROM tickets, ticket_answers
    WHERE tickets.ticket_id = ticket_answers.ticket_id

    AND ticket_answers.ticket_answer_id
        IN (
              SELECT MAX( ticket_answer_id ) 
              FROM ticket_answers
              GROUP BY ticket_id
           )
```

I know why this is showing only tickets with answers because of `WHERE` clause but can't figure it out how to change the condition..

Comment: use left join: f.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join, not an inner join.

```
SELECT tickets.*, ta.*
FROM tickets
LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_answers
ON tickets.ticket_id = ticket_answers.ticket_id
 AND ticket_answers.ticket_answer_id  IN (SELECT MAX( ticket_answer_id ) 
                                          FROM ticket_answers
                                          GROUP BY ticket_id
                                           )
```

I think the IN statement is unecessary and you can avoid it by joining to a sub select that contain only the max ticket_answer for each ticket_id like this:

```
SELECT tickets.*, ticket_answers.*
FROM tickets
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ticket_id,max(ticket_answer_id)
                 FROM ticket_answers
                 GROUP BY ticket_id) ta
ON tickets.ticket_id = ta.ticket_id
```

Comment: I every time messed up with joins. Still can't figure out which one to use and when. But eventually I will get it. First query works like charm. Thank's for the help!

Comment: Just for information, second query return `Unknown table 'ticket_answers'`.

Comment: @Garg Thats becuase you are using implicit join syntax(comma separated). Use the correct syntax and you will be able to understand it better

Comment: Yes, it's work in `SELECT` must be `tickets.*, ta.*` instead of `tickets.*, ticket_answers.*`. Anyway thank's again for help!

Comment: Just a question what can be the reason to not showing me now `ticket_id` when I list results on the page? All other info is shown.. just `ticket_id` doesn't appear.

Comment: Found the problem but don't know how to fix it. According to dev.mysql `MAX() returns NULL if there were no matching rows.` which means I can't take `ticket_id` until there is no answer to this ticket.